# Forward multiple ref to react children

Tags: reactjs, ref, react-forwardref

I have seen some articles about `forwardRef`, however couldn't be able to find an example that have a specific approach to it, basically when we are dealing with the `children props` of React and we need to forward multiple `ref` to this `children props`.

I will give an example to clarify any doubt.

Let image we have a parent component `List`, which will look like it:

```js
const List = ({  children }) => (
  <div>
   {children}
  </div>
);
```

And we have its children component `Tab`:

```js
const Tab = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

They are being used like that:

```js
<List>
 <Tab />
 <Tab />
 <Tab />
</List>
```

Therefore my question is, how I would be able to create multiple `refs` at `List`, be able to forward them to `Tab`, properly set them at each `Tab`, and them finally get its reference at `List` to work with.

If there still any doubts I'm happy to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use something like React.cloneElement and pass the references as props to the children.

```
{React.Children.map(children, childElement =>
    React.cloneElement(childElement)
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the current answer I came with:

```js
const tabReferences = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>([]);

... 

{React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
       ref: tabReferences.current[index],
  });
})}
```

Thanks Lucas!